# problem in Laravel And Vuejs , Deploy To Heroku

Tags: laravel, vue.js, heroku, deployment, laravel-8

welcome. I made an experiment project to check (laravel-with-vue) and uploaded it to Heroku. But the screen appears blank and when checking the item it appears:

```
    <body data-new-gr-c-s-check-loaded="14.1012.0" data-gr-ext-installed="" cz-shortcut-listen="true">
    <div id="app">
        <app></app>
    </div>
    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="http://blogy-new.herokuapp.com/js/app.js"></script>
    </body>
```

And this website for more details: https://blogy-new.herokuapp.com/

But on localhost it works fine:
[image]

in heroku :
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is super straight forward to fix, if you check the chrome console, you will see this error:

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://blogy-new.herokuapp.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://blogy-new.herokuapp.com/js/app.js'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

It is saying that you are asking for your `js` file using HTTP, but your page is HTTPS, so you have to rewrite your `js` file URL to HTTPS and it will be fixed:

```html
<script src="https://blogy-new.herokuapp.com/js/app.js"></script>
```

---

It is working in your localhost because it is HTTP.

Comment: when I use " http://blogy-new.herokuapp.com/ ", it is  working,
 thank you, for answering my question

Comment: Be careful that "blogy-new.herokuapp.com" goes to `http` and not `https`. If you want to add a script, try always to be absolute without the domain. A better solution to your problem would be to use `src="/js/app.js"` and it will automatically use correct protocol and domain...